# Updating columns of other tables with data stored in some other table in form of json format

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update

Let's say I have table A

| id | attribute |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Null |
| 2 | Null |
| 3 | Null |

And a table B in which data value of one column is stored in json format

| id | key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | {"attribute" : {"A_1" : 3, "A_2": 4, "A_3" : 5}} |
| 2 | Y | NULL |
| 3 | Z | NULL |

where 1 in A_1 represent the id of table A, so basically it is in the form A_id.

Now I want to retrieve this data from table B and store it into attribute column of table A.

What should be the SQL query for this?

Comment: You have tagged both [tag:mysql] and [tag:postgresql]. The syntax for this query is different in these two brands of SQL database, so you should be clear which one you are really using. Please don't add tags to your question that are not relevant to the issue.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.